# Scope of overloaded printing function c++

Tags: c++, class, printing, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use some functions for a class I have made in the overloaded printing operator however it won't allow me to use them, saying the functions weren't declared in the scope.

In the .cpp of my class BigFloat I have a function which I wish to use:

```
void BigFloat::round(BigFloat& input) 
{   
    //round the number, it works fine
}
```

I have used this for other overloaded operators such as + and - which works fine.

This is my code for printing however including the round function gives the error.

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, BigFloat y)
{
    round(y);
    out << y.sig << "e" << y.exp;
    return out;
}
```

I have declared these in the header file as

```
void round(BigFloat&);
```

and

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, BigFloat y);
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your function `round()` this way

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, BigFloat y)
{
    round( y);
    //...
}
```

it has to be a static member function in `BigFloat`:

```
class BigFloat {
//...
public:
    static void round(BigFloat& input) 
    {   
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

Then you will call it this way:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, BigFloat y)
{
    BigInt::round( y);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your code as if `round()` is a member function of `BigFloat`. If that's the case, what is it's parameter for? I'd assume it would take no parameters and instead affect the data members of the object it's invoked on. So I would change its signature & use like this:

```
void BigFloat::round()
{
  // Compute rounding, store result in `sig` and `exp`
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, BigFloat y)
{
    y.round();
    out << y.sig << "e" << y.exp;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like round is a member function of BigFloat. It would need to be a static or free function to call it in the manner that you show here.